# Content view is cutting the image when heightForRowAtIndexPath is given

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have set the image view on the content view in `xib` file. When the row height is given the rounded corner of upper image will be straight line.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//return 215;

    if (indexPath.row == 0) 
    {
      return 215.0;
    }   else
    {
      return 215.0;
    }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: what is size of imageview?

Comment: Apply this code in imageview like, [cell.photo setClipsToBounds:YES];

Comment: You should set, `imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;` or set it within the XIB it self. This can be happen when image size is greater than the cell size.

Comment: image view size is 215

Comment: i have added clipsToBounds.

Comment: Auto layout is better.   The height of ur imageview is larger than the cell height.

Comment: When i give the red color to content view, content view sits on the image..When i scroll up or down the image view rounded corner is correctly seen.

Answer (score 0):

Try an image resizing function like

```css
+ (UIImage*)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image withWidth:(int)width withHeight:(int)height
{
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    float widthRatio = newSize.width/image.size.width;
    float heightRatio = newSize.height/image.size.height;

    if(widthRatio > heightRatio)
    {
        newSize=CGSizeMake(image.size.width*heightRatio,image.size.height*heightRatio);
    }
    else
    {
        newSize=CGSizeMake(image.size.width*widthRatio,image.size.height*widthRatio);
    }


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Hope it help !

If you have a problem with it, please ask me

Comment: it remains the same.